# spring-security-oauth2 alternatives

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement OAuth authorization server and resource server using the following [project](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2/2.3.3.RELEASE) in spring. The issue I am facing is that the spring OAuth 2.0 project depends on an older version of spring than the one currently used in our repository and hence I cannot use it.

After some research, I found a [feature matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix) of spring security where there are plans on implementing the OAuth server and resource server into the spring security core. But right now they are not yet available.

So I am stuck as to how to implement the OAuth flow. Are there any good alternatives available?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link can help you out: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix . Take a look at the **Frequently asked questions** chapter (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix#frequently-asked-questions).

If you are explicitly using a Spring Boot 2 release:

> **6. Is there a way to integrate Spring Security OAuth in Spring Boot 2.0?**
>
> The Spring Security OAuth Boot 2 Autoconfig project is a port of the
>   Spring Security OAuth auto-configuration contained in Spring Boot
>   1.5.x. If you would like to use Spring Security OAuth in Spring Boot 2.0, you must explicitly include the following dependency in your project:
>
> `groupId: org.springframework.security.oauth.boot`
>
> `artifactId: spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure`